# Can I safely use gelatin to mix with 25%-35% peroxide to make a gel?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Can I safely use gelatin to mix with 25% - 35% peroxide to make a gel
or should I use glycerin?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hydrogen peroxide? You've got to be kidding me...

Comment: This sounds like a particularly dangerous case of amateur chemistry...

Comment: @mithoron it's the 30% part that is particularly frightening...

Comment: Not to tell if it was another peroxide...

Answer (score 1):

That depends. There is no way to handle 30%+ hydrogen peroxide completely safe, it is one of those ever *interesting* and *laboratory-equipment-destroying* substances. In your case, judging by the casual way you pose the question, I think it would be interesting in a *stack-exchange-user-detonating* way as well.

Please reconsider whatever you are attempting. The answer is no and no.